# Python: Translate utf-8 characters as good as possible to latin letters

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ascii, normalize

I have a text with many utf-8 characters such as `š`,`œ` and `Ó`.

There are many questions on this plattform regarding how to transform utf-8 to ascii focusing on the byte-encoding.

I would like to know wether there is a method that can be used in python to replace all of these characters to the

*most similiar analog* in the regex-pattern range
`[a-zA-Z0-9.,:?!@$€]` ( or `[α-ωΑ-Ωa-zA-Z0-9.,:?!@$€]`), i.e. to all latin (greek) letters, numbers and punctuation signs.

That would yield `š -> s`, `œ -> oe`, `Ó -> O`. but `† -> <nothing>`

In case, no close relation can be found, e.g. for symbols or smileys, they should be deleted.

I know, it is subjective which characters can be identified with each other, but maybe there is an approximate solution.

Comment: the sdlib function `unicodedata.normalize` can help with some of that, but certain of the characters you want won't be decomposed to ascii counterparts.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310) recommends something quite close to what you want (it translates `†` to `+`). If it is good enough for you, removing unwanted characters should be trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)